# Why is file's local directory being created to remote on upload

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I am creating a .NET service application that will provide FTPS functionality.

When uploading a local file to the remote location, the local file's immediate directory is recreated in the remote location.

I suspect the mask I am using is part of my problem, but I'm not sure. What is causing the directory to be recreated in the remote location?

I have tried altering the mask based on the [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

```
public static void Upload()
{
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        /* Connect
         * */
        session.Open(GetSessionOptions());

        /* Upload files
         * */
        string localFilePath = "C:\\WinScpTest\\test\\";
        string remoteFilePath = $"/Remote/{DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()}/";
        bool removeOrig = false;
        TransferOptions transferOpts = new TransferOptions
        {
            TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary,
            FileMask = "*.txt"
        };
        TransferOperationResult result = session.PutFiles(localFilePath, remoteFilePath, removeOrig, transferOpts);

    }
}
```

I would expect a local file `C:\WinScpTest\test\file.txt` to upload to `/Remote/2019/file.txt`. Instead, I see this `/Remote/2019/test/file.txt`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure with this tool, however in similiar cases it works if one removes the trailing directory delimiter. So in your case: `@"C:\WinScpTest\test\"` becomes `@"C:\WinScpTest\test"`

Comment: just remembered, I had it reversed: It is more likely that you need to remove the trailing directory delimiter from the `remoteFilePath` instead. Or both.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, please submit as an answer. Removing the trailing `/` from the `remoteFilePath` produced the expected result of `/Remote/2019/file.txt`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comment, depending on the tool being used for copying or uploading files, removing or adding a trailing directory delimiter determines wether the parent directory is to be included or not.

In most cases, such as this one, a trailing directory seperator on the target path indicates that the parent directory is to be created as well. Removing it indicates that the files shall be uploaded directly into the given folder.

In your case that would mean changing `$"/Remote/{DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()}/";` to `$"/Remote/{DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()}";`

Comment: While this "works", it's not semantically correct solution. The problem is the source path, not the destination path. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your source path syntax is ambiguous. From `C:\WinScpTest\test\`, it's not clear if you want to upload the folder `test` or files in the folder `test`.

As you want to upload files in the folder `test`, use wildcard `*`:

```
string localFilePath = "C:\\WinScpTest\\test\\*";
```

[Documentation for `localPath` argument of `Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles#localpath) says:

> Full path to local file or directory to upload. Filename in the path can be replaced with Windows wildcard to select multiple files. To upload all files in a directory, use mask `*`.

---

Though as you actually want to upload only `*.txt` files, you can drop all your `TransferOptions` code (`TransferMode.Binary` is the default anyway) and use:

```
string localFilePath = "C:\\WinScpTest\\test\\*.txt";
string remoteFilePath = $"/Remote/{DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()}/";
TransferOperationResult result = session.PutFiles(localFilePath, remoteFilePath);
```

---

The answer by @Steffen is not really correct semantically. It "works", because it tells WinSCP to upload folder `test` as `2019`. While you want to upload files in folder `test` to remote folder `2019`.

Comment: see, to me that looks...dirty? 'cause now you have something stored in a variable 'filepath' that is not a filepath and not a filemask. It is easier to read and understand the way it was done above, using the dedicated `FileMask` property.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler The OP code is against the WinSCP API specification, no matter if you like it or not.